# Photos app (iPhoto) hangs when trying to open

Tags: macos, photos, photos.app

Ive got a mac mini running OSX 10.10.5. I use the built in "Photos" app (formally iPhoto) to manage photos i take on my iPhone, which are synced back to the Photos app via iCloud.

Recently when i open the Photos app it just hangs on this screen (see attached screenshot). Ive force quit the app and re opened it a few times and the same thing happens.

What can be done to get it to work ?

[image: screenshot of Photos app "hanging"]

Comment: I had some issues with Photos depending on what version of macOS. Your best bet may be to upgrade to the latest OS and see if it works then.

Comment: @BarryMode - Normally i would agree but unfortunately i need to run 10.10.5 for one particular piece of software i use.

Comment: Have you determined if this is caused by your library or the application itself?

Comment: @Fyrefly how would i do this ?

Comment: There are a few ways to determine if the problem is the library or the application.  Probably the simplest way is by opening System Preferences and creating a brand new user account, then using that new user account to launch Photos.  This new user will have an empty photo library, but you will know if the Photos application can still be used.

Comment: Another way is holding down the "option" key when you launch Photos, this will allow you to chose which library to open (if you have more than one) or create a new library.  If Photos opens an empty library, you will confirm that the issue is a corrupt photo library.  In which case attempting the repair suggested below would be the next course of action.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing I would try before doing anything else is giving the Photos Library Repair Tool a go.

The Photos Library Repair Tool can resolve a number of issues as it analyses the entire database and, where possible, makes repairs.

Follow these steps:

1. Hold down the <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> keys as you open the Photos app
2. The following message will appear:

[image]

3. Click the blue <kbd>Repair</kbd> button to repair your Photos Library.

Comment: Thanks @monomeeth , ill give that a try. Do you know if there is any danger of losing / damaging the photos by doing this ?

Comment: I've never come across anyone who has lost their photos from doing this (either with Photos or iPhoto before it). However, I always tell people they should have a backup regime in place (be it with [Time Machine](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT201250) or something else). If you haven't been backing up, then perhaps just make a copy of your Photos Library prior to doing the Repair.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like other users over at the Apple Forum were experiencing the same issues as well. The suggested solution was:

- Eject any external hard drives, USB drives, SD cards, etc.
- Restart your computer.
- Be sure to have the latest system updates.

Source: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7013235?start=0&tstart=0